# Kernal Panic during Nvidia Driver update problems

Tags: macos, graphics, mac-pro, kernel-panic

Today I updated my Nvidia Driver.  During the process the computer experienced a kernal panic.  But it seems to have installed the driver update.  But now the menu bar on the screens inactive looks like this.  If I switch to the light menu bar, the opposite happens.

[image]

And now while typing or moving the mouse around, the computer seems to stutter quite a bit.  I reset both SMC and NVRAM, also tried drive first aid but that didn't help either.

System is a Mac Pro 5,1(Genuine) 2x3.46 Ghz 6 Core, 128GB Ram, Nvidia GeForce GTX 1080TI, Running High Sierra, Hard drive is a Sandisk Sata 3 1TB SSD connected via PCIe.

EDIT: Apparently multiple people have had the exact same thing happen today, it should be noted that the update occurred after being prompted that an update was available.